# $T \circ T = -Id_v$ $\Rightarrow$ $dim\ Z(T, v)=2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ a vector space above $\mathbb R$. and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ a
>   linear operator with $T \circ T = -Id_v$.
>
> Assuming $0 \neq v \in V$, Prove that $dim\ Z(T, v)=2$.

- $Z(T,v)$ is the $T$-cyclic subspace related to $v$.

I know that there is a maximal $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $(v,\ T(v),\  ... ,\ T^k(v))$ is basis for $Z(T,\ v)$ and from that I only need to prove that $k=1$, such that $(v,\ T(v))$ is a basis .

It's easy to tell that $T^3(v)\in span(v,\ T(v))$ because $T^3(v)=T\circ T\circ T(v)$ and we know that $T \circ T = -Id_v$ hence $T^3(v) =T(-v)=-T(v)$.

But my problem is to prove that $(v,\ T(v))$ is linearly independent. how do I show this?
I think that the fact $v \neq 0$ helps but I just cant figure out how.

How to continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $T(v)$ and $v$ are linearly dependent. Then $T(v)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, and then$$-v=T^2(v)=\lambda^2v,$$which yields $\lambda^2=-1$.